# Unique entries in a Astropy Python table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique, astropy

I have an Astropy table,

```
VHzQ_list
```

which is 463 entries long and has a column called 'na', with

```
np.unique(VHzQ_list['na'])
```

giving a list of 21 entries,

```
ATLAS
CFHQS
DELS
ELAIS 
... 
VIMOS
```

I'd like to know how many entries out of the 463 are of na='ATLAS', na=CFHQS etc. For a dataFrame I would do:

```
df.groupby('na').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

but

```
VHzQ_list.group_by('na').size().sort_values(ascending=False)
```

is throwing an

```
AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'size'
```

error. What's the Astropy Table equivalent to .size() here??

Comment: I don't know exactly what `size()` does in this case since I don't have a lot of Pandas expertise--but the astropy Table class, while having many similarities to a Pandas DataFrame, is not the same thing and there's no reason it should be expected to have the same methods and attributes.  There's probably a way to do what you're asking but if you're more familiar with Pandas you can also convert an Astropy Table to a DataFrame if you have Pandas installed. 
 See: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/pandas.html

Answer (score 1):

Python's `collection.Counter` is an easy way to get the answer here:

```
In [1]: from astropy.table import Table                                                                                                                                                        

In [2]: from collections import Counter                                                                                                                                                        

In [3]: t = Table([['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']], names=['a'])                                                                                                                   

In [4]: t                                                                                                                                                                                      
Out[4]: 
<Table length=6>
 a  
str3
----
 foo
 bar
 foo
 bar
 foo
 baz

In [5]: Counter(t['a'])                                                                                                                                                                        
Out[5]: Counter({'foo': 3, 'bar': 2, 'baz': 1})
```

To do it with Astropy, one way would be to add a column of 1 that you can then aggregate, but this is probably less flexible than pandas, as I think that the aggregate function must be applied to all columns:

```
In [23]: t['b'] = 1                                                                                                                                                                            

In [24]: t                                                                                                                                                                                     
Out[24]: 
<Table length=6>
 a     b  
str3 int64
---- -----
 foo     1
 bar     1
 foo     1
 bar     1
 foo     1
 baz     1

In [25]: tg = t.group_by('a')                                                                                                                                                                  

In [26]: tg.groups.aggregate(sum)                                                                                                                                                              
Out[26]: 
<Table length=3>
 a     b  
str3 int64
---- -----
 bar     2
 baz     1
 foo     3
```

Answer (score 0):

You already know how to do it in pandas, but this can also be easily done with `pandas.Series.value_counts` method. As pointed out, astropy Tables are not replica of pandas in functionality and scope. They have `to_pandas` and `from_pandas` convenience methods, making it easy to go back and forth.

```
VHzQ_list.to_pandas()['na'].value_counts()
```